# Drupal renaming files already in system

Tags: drupal-7

I've added quite a few images into the drupal system.

Now I've had to rename them.

I've renamed all the images and added them into the default/files folder and ran a script to update all of the files names within the file_managed table. This is both in the filename and uri.

However the changes are visible within admin portion of the site but not the front end.

If I go into the admin and to that content item and do nothing apart from save it, the changes are thn visible on the front end.

Any help with what I need to do to force it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the cache for the entire site at `admin/config/development/performance`